# How to deploy shiny apps in Azure Webapps for container?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy the standard R shiny example app in an Azure Webapp for Containers. I am using Azure container registry.

I have managed to deploy the app but the plots are not showing when I login to the webapp. It seems like shiny-server is not working proberly but I do not know why?

Comment: Could you provide the source code for your dockerfile and R code?